# Cannot access nginx when the container is in macvlan

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, portainer, macvlan

I have started nginx container, it is in macvlan. Everything works fine ping, system updating, and so on. But when I want to access nginx and type the IP of the container in my browser nothing happens why is that? I know that there is no need to do port mapping when a container is in macvlan, so i haven't done any. When i open the console of the container it says nginx is running and there are not any problems. I do not what to do anymore. For the GUI i use portainer Please help. Thank you.

I tride recreating the macvaln, reloading the nginx proces, remaking the container, manually asigning the ip. nothing helps

Comment: If the IP is right, what about the port?  Just a guess, but if you type that and get NO error, then it never made it to the right place, so the port will point the IP to the actual location likely.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.